# A variable in the while loop is not changed, ndk/android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm new in ndk. Could you please explain the following case.
This is my simple code example:

**loop.c**

```
#include "loop.h"
#include <android/log.h>

static int flag = 1;

void test_loop()
{
    while(flag)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TEST", "in the loop");
    }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TEST", "exit");
}

void set_exit_flag()
{
    flag = 0;
}
```

**loop.h**

```
#ifndef LOOP_H
#define LOOP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void test_loop();
void set_exit_flag();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include "LoopFolder/loop.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_changevariablevalues_MainActivity_Start
  (JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject pObj)
{
    test_loop();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_changevariablevalues_MainActivity_Stop
  (JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject pObj)
{
    set_exit_flag();
}
```

and in java side I have two buttons with the click listeners:

```
mStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
mStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

mStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Start();
            }
        });
    }
});

mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Stop();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and ServiceExecutor:

```
private Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

I execute start loop after mStart pressing. 
After that I click mStop and wait that loop will be stop.
But nothing happens.
In the adb console I see only

```
D/TEST    (17456): in the loop
D/TEST    (17456): in the loop
D/TEST    (17456): in the loop
..............................
D/TEST    (17456): in the loop
D/TEST    (17456): in the loop
```

messages.

Can someone help me? How to stop loop?

Comment: Ever heard of locks, volatile, synchronized, mutex, semaphor, at least anything? Then you should know what´s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two functions are not properly synchronized. They are called by different threads, one started by a click on `mStart`, the other by a click on `mStop`. This in itself is not a problem. It is also not a problem for the two threads to call native functions in parallel to each other. But it *does* become a problem when the native functions both try to access `flag` at the same time.

You need **synchronization**. Otherwise, the most (seemingly) elementary things can go wrong. For example, it's not guaranteed at all that thread 2 will see the changes to the variable in thread 1. Even a simple expression like `flag++` is not atomic anymore and can lead to all kinds of strange effects. Without synchronization, you have effectively **randomized** your app and provoke **crashes**.

Synchronization can be done in C++ and in Java, but for JNI use cases, it's usually best to leave all synchronization to the Java side. That's just the general software-engineering guideline for JNI:

*Use Java when you can, native if you must!*

A possible solution in your case is to **move the loop and the flag to Java** and reduce the JNI functions to what really must be done in C++. The `Stop` function would be entirely written in Java then, and the `cancel` flag would become an [`AtomicBoolean`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html):

```
private static AtomicBoolean cancel = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private void stop() {
    cancel.set(true);
}
```

The `Start` function would become a Java method, too, and wrap a simpler JNI function:

```
private native void print();

private void start() {
    while (!cancel.get()) {
        print();
    }
}
```

Here's the reduced JNI function:

```
void test_loop() {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TEST", "in the loop");
}
```

Here's an important final hint: you should probably use the Android SDK's [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class, which was specificially designed for cancellable background operations.

---

**Edit:** The original answer had a bug. The Java code now uses `AtomicBoolean`, which should fix the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this just deadlock? You can't call stop() while start() is executing.

Comment: I fear you are right. I originally had additional private synchronized methods, then "optimized" it before posting. Silly me. I'll see if I can fix the answer later today!

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will turn `while(flag)` into `while(1)` at higher optimization levels because it would think that no one is updating `flag` anyway. You can avoid that by defining `flag` as `volatile` which means someone can update this variable externally.

`static int flag = 1;` -> `static volatile int flag = 1;`